# Product Images not visible in backend since 1.9.3.1 update

Tags: product-images, image-upload, magento1.9.3.1

In Magento CE 1.9.2.4 I was able to see the product images in the backend in the Catalog/ProductManagement/Images screen.

I have upgraded Magento to 1.9.3.1 with magento connect.

Since then there is no images displayed in the grid. The grid only contains the first line "no image".

The images are still visible in the frontend.

I have no CreareSeo extension installed.
I have tested with up-to-date Firefox and Chrome.
I have made a copy of the shop on a test system and de-installed almost all extensions, but it is still not ok.

This is an urgent matter because it is in production and we cannot add products without images...

Thanks

Comment: can you please check log files under var/log folder , is there any word `whitelist` ?

Comment: No, there is no word "whitelist"

Comment: is images cant able to upload for new products also ?

Comment: Image display solved (see below). But No, image upload does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue is solved.

It was coming from an outdated gallery.phtml file. From the directory `\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\attributeswatches\catalog\product\helper`.

I merged it with the magento version-1.9.3.1 file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper`.

The main change in the code is probably `$_block->htmlEscape` which is now `$_block->escapeHtml`

I can now see the product images.

But the image upload process does not work. When I select a file and upload-it. Nothing appears in the grid. The files are just uploaded in `/media/tmp/catalog/product/...` but not transferred to `/media/catalog/product/...`. This second issue is solved by updating the file `/js/attributeswatches/adminhtml_product.override.js`

All is fixed.